# failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0:failed to read dockerfile: read /va.how do i solve this

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

On startup, the following error appears. OS win 10. how do i solve this problem?

> (venv) C:\shop>docker-compose up --build [+] Building 0.1s (2/2)
> FINISHED  => [internal] load build definition from shop
> 0.1s  => => transferring dockerfile: 1.78MB                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s  => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s  => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: read
> /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount057531924/shop: is a directory

Dockerfile and docker-compose are in the root of the project.

> dima@DESKTOP-1BLNH42:/mnt/c/shop$ ls Dockerfile account blog cart
> discount_system docker-compose.yaml favorites loyalty_program
> manage.py orders projectshop requirements.txt search shop venv

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . ./src

CMD ['python3', './src/manage.py', 'runserver', '0.0.0.0:8000']
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    restart: always

  web:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./shop
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    command: ['python3', './src/manage.py', 'runserver', '0.0.0.0:8000']
    depends_on:
      - pg_db

  pg_db:
    image: postgres:14
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to build without using the new [Docker BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#to-enable-buildkit-builds):

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```